# Grafana: showing multiple annotations in the same millisecond

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I've been setting up Grafana to pull some annotations from an InfluxDB database.

It seems that when multiple annotations exist within the same millisecond, Grafana will only display the last one.

Is there a way to display multiple annotations that occurred within the same millisecond ? This is for a high-time precison project so I prefer to avoid hacking it by modifying event timestamps.

Here's an example InfluxDB database:

```
> select * from events;
name: events
time                key       name   title
----                ---       ----   -----
1515664469946000001 as_start  event1 test
1515664469946999999 as_start  event4 test
1515664469947000000 as_start  event3 test
1515664469956000000 as_start  event2 test
```

I use the following query in Grafana:

```
select "name","title","key" from events WHERE $timeFilter
```

Which yields this:

graph screenshot

[image]

"event1" is not visible and was instead "overwritten" by "event4". "event3" and "event2" are visible however.

Thanks!

Comment: Grafana is likely to operate with millisecond precision. Your nanosecond timestamps are probably get rounded differently: 1515664469946000001 / 1000000 = 1515664469946.0002 for event1 while 1515664469946999999 / 1000000 = 1515664469947 for event 4 and also for event3. I suspect, that event1 is not lost - just assigned to 1 ms earlier timestamp. Try to zoom in more to find it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yuri. I tried zooming in but still no dice.